# Android Set On CLick Update & Delete ImageButton SQLite data from Adapter not working

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I already made the update and delete button inside item_report.xml, and the function in my Adapter.class. I put my recyclerview inside fragment which i made 2 tab in tablayout inside MainActivity, but when i pressed Delete or Edit/Update it's not working.

But the toast "This should be working" i put inside Update worked but not with alertdialog for update, and AlertDialog in Delete appeared & worked. I think something wrong with my Data Update & Delete but idk where cuz i thought it's no error in Run Log.

Here is my Edit & Delete in my Adapter.class:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Holder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {

        ReportDraft reportDraft = arrayList.get(position);

        final String id       = reportDraft.getId();
        final String token    = reportDraft.getToken();
        final String email    = reportDraft.getEmail();
        

        holder.judul.setText(judul);
        

        
        holder.editbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "This should be working", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                editDialog(
                        ""+position,
                        ""+id,
                        ""+token,
                        ""+email
                        

                );

            }
        });

        holder.deletebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                deleteDialog(
                        ""+id
                );
            }
        });


    }

    private void deleteDialog(final String id){

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Delete");
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure to delete it?");
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                databaseHelper.deleteInfo(id);
                //FragmentDraft frd = (FragmentDraft) ;
                ((MainActivity)context).onResume();
                Toast.makeText(context, "Aw", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            }
        });

        builder.create().show();

    }

    private void editDialog(String position, String id, String token, String email) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        builder.setTitle("Update");
        builder.setMessage("Update data?");
        builder.setCancelable(false);

        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, EditReportActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ID", id);
                intent.putExtra("TOKEN", token);
                intent.putExtra("EMAIL", email);
                

                intent.putExtra("editMode", true);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                dialogInterface.cancel();
            }
        });
    }
```

is this bcuz my fragment or main activity or what? cuz i put recyclerview inside fragment, the fragemnt is inside tablayout in my MainActivity.

***UPDATE***

The delete button success to delete but the list is not changed unless i open other activity and go back

it SOLVED, sorry i forgot to set `builder.create().show()`. Thank you

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: @RyanM the alertdialog when i press update is not showing, meanwhile when i press delete it working, the alertdialog from delete button showing up and i can delete data but the data i deleted still there unless i open other activity and go back

Comment: For deletion, you need to remove the item from the data source of the Adapter (arrayList) and call notifyDatasetChanged(). This will "reload" your list.

Comment: For you edit dialog to show you need to call: builder.create().show() at the end of editDialog method.

Comment: @gioravered i already put it onResume() in my Main Activity as you can see in my deleteDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your deletion, while removing the item from your database, is not removing the item from the Adapter's data source (your arrayList) and also not notifying the Adapter that there was a change in data.

Pass the selected item position to your deleteDialog method:

```
holder.deletebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        deleteDialog(
                position,
                ""+id
        );
    }
});
```

Add a deletion of the item from your data source:

```
private void deleteDialog(final int position, final String id){

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Delete");
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure to delete it?");
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_delete);

    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            databaseHelper.deleteInfo(id);

            arrayList.remove(position);
            notifyDatasetChanged();

            Toast.makeText(context, "Aw", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        }
    });

    builder.create().show();

}
```

The added lines are:

```
arrayList.remove(position);
```

which removes the item from the Adapter's data source

And:

```
notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Which tells the Adapter that the data was changed and it needs to reload.

As per your edit dialog not showing, it looks like you are missing the **show()** call:

Add this at the end of **editDialog** method:

```
builder.show()
```

Comment: so i don't need ```((MainActivity)context).onResume``` ?

Comment: Why would you? Your Adapter shouldn't be aware of its hosting view (Activity/Fragment).

Comment: cool, thank you. it worked, so i changed ```builder.create().show()``` into ```builder.show()``` ? what is the difference?

Comment: Sure thing. The show() method is actually calling create() before showing. So builder.create().show() is the same as builder.show()